# AWS ElasticBeanstalk "no files found to execute"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am still new to this, so please pardon the inexperience.

I am currently developing a website with a coder using python and flask, and it needs to be placed into elastic beanstalk.

The website was developed offline, and we are trying to upload it to EB.
We have followed the instructions on the AWS support, and have been able to get the "Hello World!" sample site working. However, upon reading the logs, it shows that, at the bottom, "No files found to execute"

When we upload our website, it shows the same error in the logs, but instead of showing the website, it would show Internal 500 error.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

An internal 500 error can be caused by many reasons. The "No files found to execute" issue seems interesting...Could you link to your log file?  Or, more specifically, just show the /var/log/httpd/error_log section of your log file. This is usually very helpful to diagnosing things that go wrong after a successful deployment. Sorry I can't give a definitive answer yet - 500 is very generic!

Comment: To add to Jason's answer, you can take a snapshot of your logs by following the instructions here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html